# Spring web.xml resolves only JSP default error page

Tags: html, spring, jsp

I have strange problem. I am using simple web.xml file. If I put extension to default file like *.jsp* - my default error page works. But I put *.html*, my page is ignored and default tomcat error page is displayed. The interesting thing I dont have any configuration regarding extensions(((

Works:

```
<error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
        <location>/thymeleaf_views/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Does not work:

```
<error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
        <location>/thymeleaf_views/error.html</location>
</error-page>
```

And I got error:

```
SEVERE: Exception Processing ErrorPage[exceptionType=java.lang.Throwable, location=/thymeleaf_views/error.html]
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

It seems Spring somehow resolves without any checks only **.jsp* but all other extensions should be somehow resolved since only *jsp* works. Any other extension is rejected.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Weird nobody still answered this. Isn't anyone else facing the same problem?

Comment: @Sajib. I already forgot aout this issue. I resolved it but dont remember already how. As I remember - by adding specific view resolver into spring xml file. You can try it.